# Jquery .html .slice, but retain formatting tags

Tags: jquery, html, slice

I'm using a jQuery library called dropcaps.js, to target the first letter of a `<p>` tag, and wrap it in a `span`. This is working as expected, however the remaining part of the `<p>` has all of the tags stripped such as `<a>`, `<strong>`, `<em>` etc. Is there a way to edit the below to retain these formatting tags?

```
// Init dropcaps
// Dropcaps
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Isolate the first letter of paragraphs and place within <span>
    $('p.has-drop-cap').each(function() {
        var text = $.trim($(this).text());
        var firstLetter = text.substr(0,1);
        $(this).html('<span class="initial-letter">' + firstLetter + '</span>' + text.slice(1));
    }); 

    // Init dropcap.js and target <span>
    var dropcaps = document.querySelectorAll(".initial-letter");
    // Set dropcap number of rows to fit and baseline position
    window.Dropcap.layout(dropcaps, 5, 5);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `html()` instead of `text()` to get the content string as html

You can also simplify a bit using `html(function)` instead of `each`

```
$('p.has-drop-cap').html(function(_, currHtml) {
  currHtml = $.trim(currHtml);
  var firstLetter = currHtml.substr(0, 1);
  return '<span class="initial-letter">' + firstLetter + '</span>' + currHtml.slice(1));
});
```

Note this assumes the paragraphs all start out with raw text and no immediate children like `<b>`, `<strong>` , `<img>` etc

Comment: Thanks for the response @charlietfl! Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be working, it still strips everything out?

Comment: Create a few sample paragraphs in jsfiddle or other sandbox site